# C# Update a Variable

Tags: c#

I want to enter animals using a variable. For example:

```
private void button14_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string newAnimal;
    newAnimal = "pig";
    if (textBox1 = newAnimal)
    {
        //some other code 
    }
}
```

Is it possible to update the variable newAnimal with a different animal, say cow in a different textbox, say textbox2? I cant figure out how to update the variable

Thank you. I am a beginner. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: you must put `==` instead of `=` in if statement. and yes you can do.

Comment: https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23%20set%20value%20from%20textbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to put the content of `textbox2` into the `newAnimal` string:

```
private void button14_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string newAnimal;
    newAnimal = "pig";
    if (textBox1.Text == newAnimal)
    {
        newAnimal = textbox2.Text;
    }
}
```

Note that to check for equality, you should use the `==` operator instead of `=`.